# Как сделать так, чтоб по нажатию на кнопку в TextView был текст с определённой строки элемента EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-textview

Я хочу сделать так: ввёл я текст в EditText, например, "Привет, Мир!" на 7-ой строке (текст можно вводить случайный), нажал на кнопку и текст вывелся в TextView (не весь, а 7-ая строка)

Answer (score 3):

1. Вбиваем в гугл [android edittext get line](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20edittext%20get%20line)
2. Идём по первой [ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11247388/3212712)
3. Копируем код:

   ```
   String multiLines = streetEt.getText().toString();
   String[] streets;
   String delimiter = "\n";

   streets = multiLines.split(delimiter);
   ```

---

Т.е., если разделитель строк - перенос строки ("\n"), то, получив весь текст методом `getText()`, мы можем разбить его на части (на массив строк) методом `split`, принимающим разделитель строк.